# jQuery datepicker stretched out (wrong layout)

Tags: jquery, html, uidatepicker

[image]

For some reason, my jQuery datepicker looks like the one above... I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.

Code (shortened):

```
//References

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

//Datepicker code

<div id="datepicker" name="datepicker"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            altField: "#realdate",
            altFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
        });
    });
</script>

//Hidden field to store my date

<input type="hidden" name="realdate" value="" id="realdate">
```

Placing the div under the script doesn't work. What DOES work however is the following:

```
<input type='text' id='datepicker' name='datepicker' />
```

This displays an input field that, when clicked upon, displays a correctly rendered datepicker. But I don't want the input field, I just want the datepicker...

***EDIT***

Ok, It seems I've found the evil-doer:

```
.ui-helper-clearfix::after {
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

from the jquery css. 
My problem is fixed by removing "display: block;"
Problem is, this css file is located online. I can't put it offline in my own css folder because it references a bunch of images etc. Is there any way I can override this class or something to make my fix work?

Comment: The jQuery UI Datepicker has to be tied to an input field. What are you planning to do with just the datepicker? The selected value needs to go _somewhere_... If you don't want the input field visible, then use some CSS to hide it.

Comment: The selected value goes into a hidden field. Everything works fine just as it is now, just the lay-out is screwed up...

Comment: @Matthias: It looks fine to me on a fresh jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cKcTz/ Perhaps you have some other CSS rules which are inadvertently being applied?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem that there are any conflicting CSS rules. When I paste my css file in jsFiddle it shows up correctly as well...

Comment: @Matthias: There must be something else going on in your environment. Unfortunately, with the info provided, I can't be of more help!

Comment: try taking the minimal amount of code and start adding stuff to it e.g. an empty HTML file and slowly add css and js files until it breaks

Comment: see Edit, I might have found a reason for it to fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate the style definition in your own stylesheet with a stronger selector, overriding the offending style:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-helper-clearfix::after {
        display: inline;  /* or whatever it should be */
    }
</style>
```

Just having the style definition later in the document is enough to make the selector stronger.  But you could play it safe by also strengthening the selector by adding the element name: `div.ui-helper-clearfix::after`.  (assuming the element is a div... I don't know what it really is.)